# set visible=true no use in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game similar to the traditional magic tower and now I have a problem when dealing with the battles between the monster and the braver.

Here's my code in update():

```
function update(){
   // ...
   game.physics.arcade.collide(braver, monsters, battle, null, this);
   // ...
}
```

And here's my battle():

```
function battle(player, monster) {
    var x = (player.attack > monster.defence ? player.attack - monster.defence : 0);
    var y = (monster.attack > player.defence ? monster.attack - player.defence : 0);
    battleScene.visible = true;
    while (1) {
        if (Date.now() > battleTimer) 
        {
            battleTimer = Date.now() + 1000;
            monster.health -= x;
            if (monster.health <= 0) {
                monster.kill();
                player.gold += monster.gold;
                player.exp += monster.exp;
                break;
            }
            player.health -= y;
            if (player.health <= 0) {
                player.kill();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    battleScene.visible = false;
}
```

`battleScene` is a group, the battle box. What makes me crazy is that battleScene doesn't show on the screen at all (even with `battleScene.visible = true`).

I've tried `game.world.bringToTop(battleScene);` but it doesn't work either. So how can I fix that bug?

Answer (score 0):

What type of object is the `battleScene` ? if it's a [`Phaser.State`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.State.html) you need to start that state with the state [Manager (Documentation)](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.StateManager.html)

```
game.state.start('battle_scene_key')
```

If it's a `Phaser.Sprite` you need to add it to the game's world in order for it to draw.

```
// assuming `this` is a Phaser.State
state.add.existing(battleScene)
```